# getUser does not work in 4.0.4 master webchat client

Tags: smooch

I downloaded today the last release (4.0.4, from yesterday) of the webchat client from github and deployed in in my website.

I have detected that Smooch.getUser() returns 'undefined' when a new user is detected until this new user send his first message, but it doesn't happen on returning users.

```
<script>
    Smooch.on('ready', function(){
        console.log('the init has completed!');
    });

    var skPromise = Smooch.init({appId: 'myAppId'});

    skPromise.then(
        function()
        {
            var u = Smooch.getUser();
            console.log(u._id);
        });
    );
</script>
```

**smooch_local.html:26 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at smooch_local.html:26
    at anonymous**

---

But, if i send any message after the promise has resolved, and later I try to recover the userId, the variable gets defined. It didn't happen in this way in previous 3.x.x releases of the Web Messenger chat.

This code returns a valid userId:

```
<script>
    Smooch.on('ready', function(){
        console.log('the init has completed!');
    });

    var skPromise = Smooch.init({appId: 'myAppId'});

    skPromise.then(
        function()
        {
            Smooch.sendMessage({type: 'text', text: 'x'}).then(
            function(){
            var u = Smooch.getUser();
            console.log(u._id);
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

This is the console ouptut:

**12:21:20.165 the init has completed!**
**12:21:22.947 smooch_local.html:28 1102fdee2b7d3c2abb639cbe**

Does anyone knows if it's a bug or a new feature from v4.x releases?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour for Web Messenger 4.x - users are no longer automatically created at init time. Instead, user creation is deferred until after they send a message. This was mentioned in the [release notes](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-web/releases/tag/4.0.0) for v4.0.0

> Web Messenger now uses a new optimized initialization sequence. This new sequence alters the timing of key events such as creating a new user or establishing a websocket connection.

Alternatively, you can [pre-create](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#pre-create-app-user) a user with a `userId` before the Web Messenger is initialized, and use the `login` method to initialize as that user, but this may or may not be appropriate depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I try to recover the userId and if it isn't defined, I create a new userId for the new session without assigning a JWT token. The problem now is that I issue a **Smooch.destroy()** command,and after this, Smooch.Init({appId:'myAppId',userId:'newUserId'}). At this point, Smooch raises an error telling: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". Thanks

Comment: This is a bug that should be fixed in v4.0.5 (https://github.com/smooch/smooch-web/releases/tag/4.0.5)